# How do I add onto an existing value in a column of mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Is there a way to add values together to an existing column using hibernate statements? I have a web application that takes user input and adds points to their record in the database if the input is correct. So if correct, they get 50 points and that populates the points column in mysql, second time right should update the column to 100 and so on... The only ones I can find are insert and update but those just insert or replace, not add onto.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  You can't just add onto a cell in a mysql table.  First you need to select the cell into a variable.  Then you  need to add onto that variable and finally you can now go back to your mysql table and update the cell with the new value.What are you using for your backend? php?

Comment: please share what have you tried to solve the problem and any problems you come across?

Comment: @DCR i am using java

Comment: The operation you need to perform is an `UPDATE`. In SQL, the query would be something like `UPDATE points SET points = points + 50 WHERE some_condition = some_value;` See @Abdelmjid EL KIHEL's answer below because you will do this with Hibernate and not raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you return the object using (find) and you change the value of the attribute that you want like **`user.setRecord(user.getRecord() + 50)`** and you call the function (merge) of the entitymanager.